# Volley android library post request not working

Tags: android, android-volley

I know there are similar looking questions but I have searched many of them and they don't seem to be working for me.  So what I want to do is send a post request with a simple string `"ON"/ "OFF"` as the data. Something like this works (for some $URL):

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"  -d "ON" "$URL"
```

Here is the code I am trying and after reading lots of code and answers here I thought it would work but it isn't.

What am I missing ? I get a `400 error` from server.

```
Request request = new StringRequest
                    (Request.Method.POST, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Command was sent successfully");
                                }},
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Got command error for " + url + " command " + command + " error " + error.getMessage());
                                }
                            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
                 //   headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                 //   headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");
                    return headers;
                }
                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return command.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "failed converting" + e.getMessage());
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Is it all what you have? Any error?

Comment: Some more code for example with RequestQueue queue. And relevant logs

Answer (score 1):

You have to override getParams()

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {  

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
    params.put("postData", "my simple on/off string");  
    return params;  

};
```